# Look up table to System.Text.Encoding

Tags: c#, .net-4.5

Lets say I have the `System.Text.Encoding` properties stored in a database:

```
ID|Name
1 |ASCII
2 |BigEndianUnicode
3 |Default
4 |Unicode
5 |UTF32
6 |UTF7
7 |UTF8
```

How would I be able to cast the value in my data base to the System.Text.Encoding object?

I would expect to be able to do something like: `Encoding EncodingType = (Encoding)("ASCII");`

Please note I am not attempting to figure out the encoding of a specific string or value, this encoding will be used as a value that will be loaded during run time to make a connection to a SMPP provider.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the static [`Encoding.GetEncoding`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t9a3kf7c(v=vs.110).aspx) method to get the corresponding Encoding object, e.g., `Encoding EncodingType = Encoding.GetEncoding("ASCII")`.